# 2D Moving player with canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

So I was told to create a simple game in android using canvas only for a school project (meaning I can't use any extensions or game engines beside the ones that come with android), and I wanted to create a simple 2d game with a player walking around.

I did it like that:

```
public GameView(Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
super(c);
this.c=c;
this.Sprite=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walk1);
this.Sprite=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Sprite, Sprite.getWidth()*2, Sprite.getHeight()*2, false);
sprite2=new Sprite("Spicy",Sprite);
this.requestFocus();
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
animate1();
}
```

I created a view class, loaded a simple player sprite, created sprite class and an handler -

```
public void animate1(){
    handlerAnimation100 = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        invalidate();
            handlerAnimation100.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    };

    handlerAnimation100.postDelayed(r, 1);
}
```

that does invalidate every 0.001 seconds for the game time and animation.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
sprite2.Draw(canvas);   
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    sprite2.Update(keyCode);
    invalidate();
    return false;
}
```

on onDraw i called the draw function in the sprite class and onkeydown I sent the key pressed to the update function in the sprite class.

Now for the sprite class there isn't something special:

```
public class Sprite {
      enum State
      {
          Walking
      }
      State mCurrentState = State.Walking;

      int mDirection = 0;
      int mSpeed = 0;
      int mPreviousKeyboardState;
    private String spriteName;
    Bitmap sprite;
     int SPRITE_SPEED = 5;
     int MOVE_LEFT = -1;
     int MOVE_RIGHT = 1;
    private float mScale = 1.0f;
    Point Position;
    public Sprite(String name,Bitmap sprite) {
        this.sprite=sprite;
        this.spriteName=name;
     Position=new Point(150,150);
    }
    public void Update(int keyboard)
    {
        int aCurrentKeyboardState = keyboard;

        UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);

        mPreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;


    }
    private void UpdateMovement(int aCurrentKeyboardState)
    {
        if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
        {
            mSpeed = 0;
            mDirection = 0;

            if (aCurrentKeyboardState==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)
            {
                mSpeed = SPRITE_SPEED;
                mDirection = MOVE_LEFT;
            }
            else if(aCurrentKeyboardState==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D)
            {
                mSpeed = SPRITE_SPEED;
                mDirection= MOVE_RIGHT;
            }
            Position.x += mDirection * mSpeed;
        }
    }
    public void Draw(Canvas c)
    {            
        c.drawBitmap(sprite, Position.x,Position.y, null);
    }
}
```

I just change the position of the image and move it depending on the key pressed.

---

**Now here is the problem:** 
Using handler and invalidate was the only option I was able to find to replace "Game time" that appears in game engines, and although it works, it works very choppily, if the speed of the player is high it looks like it jumps pixels and if its low the animation is blurry and very slow, it looks like the invalidate takes more time and it happens not every 0.001 seconds but 0.5 seconds or so.

**Here is how it looks like:**
 
Slow speed (blurry and very slow):
 
[image]
 
Faster Speed (choppy not smooth):
 
[image]

---

**Is there a better way to do it, again with only using what android offers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads! However the handler is not the root of your problem judging by how slow your animation is running and how choppy the fast one is, you are probably using a canvas tied into an ImageView? This is not very fast at all. You should look into using a SurfaceView (works with lower APIs but not the fastest) or into TextureView (super fast, I had to delay my thread cause the animation was just a blur). Both of these rely on canvas at their core.

There are lots of examples out there on in internets on how to code these and you can adapt them for your purposes. To give you a place to start you can look [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-seriescomparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same) at some samples I wrote.

Comment: Thank you, I tried surfaceview and it already works a lot better, next I'll try textureview and see what fits my needs more

Comment: if you can help me here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483696/make-a-sprite-jump it will be amazing, thanks!